# Scaling a 4-bit Number Using Bitwise Operations (Not Floating Numbers)

Tags: c, floating-point, integer, bit-manipulation, microcontroller

I'm wondering how I can multiply a floating variable "gain" value (decimal 0.0 - 1.0) to a variable 4-bit discrete value (16 discrete levels) to end up with a scaled value, all by NOT using floating-point math/numbers (preferably by using bit-wise operations, etc). I'm programming a PIC 16-bit microcontroller in C (XC16 compiler) to control a multicolored LED array. Each LED can take on 16 levels of intensity. P is the original LED "pattern" intensity for that instant. C is the pattern scale value to apply to P. S is the final scaled pattern value.

For example, I have a value P = 0x0F that I want to scale to 50% of its original value (i.e., multiply by C = 0.50), to end up with 'S' = 0x08 (rounding up); or any combination where P = 0x00:0x0F and C = 0.0:1.0. The result 'S' should end up being a 4-bit number (16 discrete values, 0x00 through 0x0F), but scaled 0-100% of the original value depending on 'C'. Obviously there will have to be some ceiling/floor/rounding methods employed, as well as maybe some type casting.

Any ideas? This seems so easy, but I'm having trouble. If all else fails, I can use floating-point operations to do it. But, I like the idea of using a more efficient method (and learning something) rather than brute forcing it with floating numbers and rounding.

*The factor 'C' could be anything that scales (or normalizes) 'P', requiring at least a short int (BYTE) type that only uses the lower nibble, into 16 levels; 0/15 through 15/15. 'P' is already a 4-bit number, but I want to apply a "gain" to it to scale it down from its given value (could be 0/15 to 15/15), or keep it the same if the gain value = 100%. For example if P = 15/15 (0x0F) and and C = 100%, S = 15/15 (0x0F). Now if P = 8/15 (0x07) and C = 50%, then S = 4/15 (0x03). If P = 0, then all S = 0. If C = 0, then all S = 0. For cases where P > 0 and C > 0 but gives S = 0 (i.e., low values of P and C), I will have a condition to set S = 1 (1/15 = 0x01). This condition is problem specific.

Comment: If `C` was not a `float`, this operation would be trivial.  Can the scale factor be an `int`?  `C` in the range `0.0 to 1.0` has ~16 million of combinations.  If one knew more about the generation of `C`, some simplifications could be had.

Answer (score 3):

Positive floating-point numbers increase with the bits of their representation interpreted as an integer. If you wish to avoid floating-point operations, you can do a binary search of th bits of the representation of the input in an array of the bits of the representations of 1/16, 2/16, 3/16, 4/16, …

```
union u { float f; uint32_t u; } tbl[] = { 0.0f, 0.0625f, 0.125f, … };

int convert_to_4_bits(float f) {
  union u v;
  v.f = f;
  int i;
  /* binary search of v.u in tbl, 
       using 4 32-bit integer comparisons, 
       leaving result in i */
  if (v.u >= tbl[8].u)
    i = 8;
  else
    i = 0;
  if (v.u >= tbl[i+4].u)
    i += 4;
  if (v.u >= tbl[i+2].u)
    i += 2;
  if (v.u >= tbl[i+1].u)
    i += 1;
  return i;
}
```

I will leave it for you to decide the edge cases (i.e. the exact values in `tbl` and whether to use `>=` or `>` for comparison. Note that `tbl[0]` is never used, so you could optimize a bit there at the detriment of simplicity.

You say in your question that you wish to use bitwise operations. No problem: replace all `+=` in the program with `|=`.

Answer (score 1):

There is I think 2 things to do: first, convert the float to an integer. Of course, not an integer from 0 to 1 (which will not be useful), but to a value from 0 to 2^n, choosing n for best precision and speed. Considering that you do not probably need to be very precise (working to scale 0 to 15), n=15 is certainly enough (values from 0 to 32768) as you probably want to stay inside a 16 bits value (probably the best performance for a 16 bits architecture), and we can probably go even lower (n=8 -> 0 to 256 is probably good enough, n=12 -> 0..4096 is interesting as multiplying it by a 0..15 value will keep it inside 16 bits value).

If you know the exact float point format for your platform, you can do that by extracting the higher bits of the mantissa (see http://kipirvine.com/asm/workbook/floating_tut.htm for more information on binary floating point format) and bit wise shift it using the exponent.

After that, multiply by the 0..15 value and divide by n^2 (which is the same as bit wise down shift by n).

If you do not want to use an integer multiplication and have a few bytes of memory to spare, you can use some kind of table lookup with pre-calculated values. You only have 0..15 possibilities for one of the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

Using 16-bit integer values...
where P = 0x0000:0x000F, and C = 0x0000:0x000F  (P and C take on 16 discrete levels)

Pscaled = (((P+1) << 4) * C)

Finally,
**S = Pscaled >> 8**